# Magento customer webservice / api

Tags: xml, flash, api, magento

I need some sort of way to handle Magento's customer login, customer account creation and order checkout via some kind of webservice to be used for Flash, preferably XML.
As far as I know the Magento API doesn't have these features. I found the Mammoth Webservices extension but it seems that the project is inactive judging from heir site.
Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own module to handle these features the way you want.

Or extend the API. The power of Magento is exactly his extensibility.